# Extracting content out of Email within Odoo

Tags: python, email, odoo, odoo-8

i try to make my problem as clear as possible to you.
I have set up an incoming email server within Odoo. Every incoming mail creates a new applicant for my hr_recruitment.

The default code for this action in the module looks like this:

```
def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg, custom_values=None, context=None):
    """ Overrides mail_thread message_new that is called by the mailgateway
        through message_process.
        This override updates the document according to the email. """ 

if custom_values is None:
        custom_values = {}
    val = msg.get('from').split('<')[0]
    defaults = {
        'name':  msg.get('subject') or _("No Subject"),
        'partner_name': val,
        'email_from': msg.get('from'),
        'email_cc': msg.get('cc'),
        'user_id': False,
        'partner_id': msg.get('author_id', False), }
```

Example for the incoming email body:

> User ID: 1234
>   User Name: Nicolas Mustermann
>   Programming Skills: Java, C++, Python
>   Country: Germany
>   etc.

Everything works fine but i want that e.g. 'name' gets its value (Nicolas Mustermann) out of the email body. 
  How do i have to change the line :'partner_name': val, to achive that?

Best regards

Comment: Oh, you`re right... im changing it in the post, thx

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by changing the line.  Once you have the 'val' variable that contains the person's name, what exactly do you want to do with that data?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the e-mail body is in the `msg` variable.  If that is the case then you want to get a substring that only contains the name on the second line and pass that to your code that creates the applicant.  Here is a function that does that and accounts for some corner cases along the way:

```
def get_name_from_msg(msg):
    prefix = 'User Name: '
    name_start = msg.find(prefix)
    if name_start == -1:
        return None
    name_start += len(prefix)
    name_end = msg.find('\n', name_start)
    return msg[name_start:] if name_end == -1 else msg[name_start:name_end]
```

This function will return None if there exists no 'User Name: ' in the `msg`.

I would like someone to post a more "pythonic" way of doing this, however.  I feel that this method is very bulky.

Comment: You are right, the name is defined over the email address... but i need it to be read out of the email body. The thing is, i send the emails myself to the incoming email server to create new applicants. But if i do it, the applicant is named after me, because it is defined with my email address... to get the right name automatically, i have to use the informations within the email body --- cant i use the command .getline or somthing like this? so directly navigate to the second line with the name?

Comment: Thank you, i will try it =) I´ll you know if it works